# Unable to find firefox developer edition event listener breakpoints in the debugger?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools, javascript-debugger, firefox-developer-edition

In Chrome, a user can open up the DevTools Debugger and easily select an event listener breakpoint on the right in the "Sources" Pane.

I have been unable to find these features in the Firefox Developer Edition debugger. Curiously, when visting the Firefox Developer Edition website, they have a video that shows a user easily opening up the inspector, switching to the debugger, and clicking a panel on the right to bring up all these event breakpoints. In the version of Firefox Developer Edition that I am using (54.0a2), however, **these buttons do not exist**.

[image: Firefox Developer Edition debugger panel]

I have literally clicked every button on the debugger panel and am left scratching my head.

It seems almost unbelievable these features do not exist or were removed in a "developer edition" browser. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Note, the [Firefox Developer Edition](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/04/simplifying-firefox-release-channels/) is officially discontinued and Firefox Developer Edition 54 users will be moved to the Firefox Beta channel.

Answer (score 0):

Setting breakpoints on event listeners is obviously not yet implemented in the new debugger UI, but there's already a [request to add it](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html/issues/2652).

Note that you can simply switch back to the old debugger frontend by unchecking the *Enable new debugger frontend* option in the [settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings#Debugger) (only available in Firefox Nightly):

[image: *Enable new debugger frontend* option]

or by going to [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) and setting the preference `devtools.debugger.new-debugger-frontend` to `false`.